# Many SYN_RECV connections in netstat

Tags: ipv6

When I do `netstat -tn`, I consistently see a lot of connections from a few ipv6 addresses (the fe80:: ones; usually around or exactly 4096 of them). I'm unable to find the addresses on WHOIS, and blocking them via ufw or iptables doesn't seem to work. Am I being attacked? Is it a SYN flood?

```
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:41510 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:50782 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:27544 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:44052 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:49154 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:26306 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:61276 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:36288 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::a236:9fff:f:32822 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:33540 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:46254 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:34114 SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:141:1d3::2:443 fe80::b696:91ff:f:39238 SYN_RECV
```

Comment: It is likely that your ISP is also using IPv6 (many people use IPv6 without knowing it). If you are using a consumer-grade router (off-topic here), your network devices are probably getting IPv6 addressing from your router. Most hosts prefer IPv6 over IPv4, and that is a connection attempt from a host on your local network.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations.

Answer (score 1):

`fe80::/10` is a *link-local address* that isn't routable. Those SYNs/connection attempts are coming from your own network.